# Change Xcode Project's build path without breaking modules search path

Tags: xcode, build, frameworks, config

I need to change the build path of my project to be folder in my project (without changing the global Xcode preferences), and I used this configuration I found in Stackoverflow:

```
//Intermediate build files go here
PROJECT_TEMP_DIR = $(SRCROOT)/build/$(PROJECT_NAME).build

// Build-related files for the active build configuration go here
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $(SRCROOT)/build/$CONFIGURATION

// The final product executables and other build products go here
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR = $(SRCROOT)/build/$CONFIGURATION
```

But now the build is failing because he cannot find the frameworks...

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: could you show the error?  also, what are the current framework settings (i.e. where are they looking for them)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann 'EarlGrey' not found
What framework settings do you need?

Comment: could you do a screenshot of the error?  Also, is this happening in the app target or the test target?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann App Target.
added the image...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, work for me:
  1. Go to File -> Project settings (or Workspace Setting)
  2. Click the Advanced button
  3. Click "Custom" and select "Relative to Workspace" in the pull down
  4. Done

Comment: This works but is local to the machine, it cannot be stored in version control to share with the rest of the team…

Answer (score 0):

If your test target is failing to build, then you need to add the same build rules to your test target.